# Animating body scrollTop in PhantomJS doesn't change scrollTop value

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

As part of a component test I'm trying to verify an element is scrolled in PhantomJS. While the scroll code works fine in our app, the `scrollTop` of the element never changes when run in Phantom.

For the test, I ensure the body has a max-height, just in case.

```
$body = $('body').css({
    'max-height': '1000px',
    overflow: 'scroll'
});
```

Then I add some elements which extend further than the body.

```
$body.append(
    '<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>' +
    '<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>' +
    '<div style="height: 2000px;" data-uid="1"></div>');
```

Then I animate the scrollTop, given the third div as `$element` (so the `offset().top` == 4000).

```
$body.animate({
    scrollTop: $element.offset().top
}, 150, function() {
    // $body.scrollTop() is still 0
});
```

Yet after the animation has finished, the body isn't reporting any new scrollTop.

I've been unable to find documentation or other examples that explain this issue.

Comment: The animation does scroll right? The value is not changed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Even if I set `$('body').scrollTop(4000);`, `$('body').scrollTop()` still returns 0.

Comment: I should also not that, JQuery animate accepts css properties, that means it accepts top, but not scrollTop

Comment: This works perfectly fine in Chrome/Firefox/etc. It's only failing in Phantom

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried setting `viewportSize` of the page? I'd guess that if the size is not set, the whole page gets rendered so that there is no need for scrolling (whole page is visible in the viewport).

[Here is the description](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) of that property